# Java Text Editor Api

Tags: java

I want to put a text editor in my java application.
The editor has to have basic formatting features like fonts, bold, color etc..

Ideally I'd like to just add the Text Editor as a component to a JFrame.

Is there any library for this?

I think this could be simply done using a JEditPane, but I don't want to
go through all the trouble of making an editor if I could just import one.

Comment: Which ones have you found through Google, and why couldn't you use them?

Comment: There is a related question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196980/can-anyone-recommend-a-java-rich-text-editor

Answer (score 3):

From [this post on java.net](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=251114): have a look at [Ekit](http://www.hexidec.com/ekit.php).

Answer (score 2):

The secton from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) has a quick example how this might be done.

You can't just plug in a component and expect it to work as an editor. You need to add toolbars and menu items for your font, bold color features etc. The editor kits provided by Swing support all these basic features.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) (see the Java Web Start demo on the page), in particular the `JXEditorPane` component.