# Integrate a text editor in Java desktop application

Tags: swing, java

I would love to find a solution to integrate a simple text editor in a Java desktop application using Swing! (like tinyMCE in an HTML)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196980/can-anyone-recommend-a-java-rich-text-editor

Answer (score 2):

Java already supports basic text editing. See [how to use editor panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).