# Is there a Java SDK HTML based text area plugin

Tags: java, plugins, textarea, jtextarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone recommend a Java rich text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196980/can-anyone-recommend-a-java-rich-text-editor)

i need something like [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for Java SDK. Does a tool like this exist? Maybe Java has a class of it's own that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JEditorPane` comes closest in the Java Standard API, though it's not an out-of-the-box solution. [Here's a Demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TextComponentDemo) that shows it in action. There may be third-party components built upon it that provide more functionality.

Answer (score 2):

[JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) may be the closest thing to what you are looking for. It renders HTML out of the box... but it would require some work to add WYSIWYG editing.

Comment: Do add the link to [How to use JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), so that the seeker can get a proper idea.