# Word processing Component for swing

Tags: java, swing, text-editor, word-processor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone recommend a Java rich text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196980/can-anyone-recommend-a-java-rich-text-editor)

I'm writing an application that needs a basic word processor.
It should be able to change font, size, bold, italic, undo/redo, maybe colour.

It shouldn't be too complex since part of what will be wrote in it will be used as a key for a DB query in order to translate it in few languages (addendum: i'm not writing a translator), and i would like to add auto-completition.

Is there an (open source) word processing component that could be like the one i need?
If not, is there any tutorial that can give me at least some hints about how to write it myself (i found a lot of confusion on the net about EditorKit and Document and how it should be used)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few to look into

- [OOBean](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/JavaBean/The_OOoBean_by_Example) - Uses a component of Open Office (might be overkill)
- [Metaphase](http://kenai.com/projects/metaphaseeditor)
- [Memoranda](http://memoranda.sourceforge.net/)
- A quick google search for 'Java Swing rich text editor' returns many more

Comment: I'm seraching 'java rtf editor' on google since 2 days and haven't found anyone good yet! I'll look into the ones you linked