# Writing simple RTF files in Java

Tags: java, swing, file-io, rtf, jeditorpane

I am using Java 6, Windows XP, Eclipce Java EE IDE Juno, Swing.
Im looking for the simplest solution without adding any new librarys.
To describe my question i will first start with describing my goal.

My idea is to print out in the following format:

---

### Heading

**subHeading**

stuffs stuffs stuffs
stuffs stuffs stuffs

---

I would like to get to this goal by using RTF file format. 
What i have concluded is that i should probably use JEditorPane and some how add line by line formated text into the editor. 
After im done i would like to write the JEditorPane to file and save it.

So, that said. There are some questionmarks here i do not seem to figure out.

What "standard" class can i use to create RTF formated string lines?
Is JEditorPane the best container for a RTF document?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: *"Do this work?"*  What happened when you do'd it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation has everything you need. (http://goo.gl/EJSpx)

- Create javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit by calling createEditorKitForContentType
- Add newly created editorkit to JEditorPane by calling registerEditorKitForContentType (notice that support for RTF is limited)

Hope this put you on the right path.

See this thread as well [Can anyone recommend a Java rich text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196980/can-anyone-recommend-a-java-rich-text-editor)