# How to put javaScript code in Java program/application?

Tags: java, javascript

Trying to put in your application code of Ace Editor: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding.
I found something like this: http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/
and I put this code:

```
engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js"));
```

But I have build errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1513) in <Unknown source> at line number 1513
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:224)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
    at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.main(JavaApplication9.java:28)
Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1513)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3770)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3748)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3833)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.nameOrFunction(ScriptRuntime.java:1826)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1765)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1785)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:849)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:430)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:109)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3160)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:173)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1169)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:214)
    ... 2 more
```

Do any of you know how can I do this?
Thans for help and Happy Holidays!

Comment: What build errors do you have?

Comment: Because it is this too much I'll give it a link: http://pastebin.com/yss10VFd

Comment: I edited it and pasted the linked stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you are executing a Javascript file out of context.

This Javascript file is usually executed with the browser JS engine so if you are not in that context you could not access to some objects like navigator, window... etc.

Comment: So this can not be done? Is there a way?
Or is there a similar program in Java, which I can use?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That guide is intended to embed ACE in a web application.

Comment: Yes it is and I know it. I want to make a program in the style of a notebook that will be used Ace as a text editor.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853071/wysiwyg-text-editor-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196980/can-anyone-recommend-a-java-rich-text-editor

Comment: @Ursinus It can be done with some code, however this code was clearly designed only to be used in a webpage context, trying to get the computed CSS of elements and asking about the user's browser.

Comment: Ok I understund. And if you put it in with the JEditorPane?
Could we save the code created in the editor?

Comment: Ok. I give up the idea. Just tell me how to do syntax highlighting in a simple text editor?